# Unexpected token in JSON argument in POST request

Tags: node.js, typescript, ionic2

I am trying to make a POST request to a nodejs server from an Ionic application work, but I stumbled on this error.

```
Http failure response for http://127.0.0.1:3000/services/user/signin: 500 Internal Server Error", SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0;
```

I have access to both the application and the API server. Task at hand, trying to send credentials to the server, which will check if those credentials are recognized and will send a response. The server side code works just fine, since I have a web app accessing to the same resources and working like a charm.

Here goes the code.

Home page:

```
doLogin() {
  this.remoteService.login(this.user);
}
```

user is a key value array

```
user = { email:'', password:'' };
```

Now for the login function in the remoteService injectable:

```
login(user){
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    console.log(JSON.stringify(user));
    this.http.post(serviceUrl+'/user/signin', JSON.stringify(user), {headers: headers}).subscribe(
        function(response) { console.log("Success Response" + response)},
        (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
            if (err.error instanceof Error) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log(err);
            }
        }
    );
}
```

I used this line

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(user));
```

to test the function argument for JSON correctness, and it's a charm.

Finally, this is the nodejs server code

```
if(label === 'signin') {
    return function (req, res, next) {
    {
        var user = JSON.parse(req.query.user);
        db.query('SELECT username as id FROM user where email = ? and password = ?', [user.email,user.password], function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
              next(err);
            }
            else {
              if(result.length === 1) {
                delete user.password;
                req.session.user = result[0];
                req.result = 400;
              }
              else
              {
                req.result = 404;
              }
              next();
            }
          });
        }
    };
}
```

Could you please help me fix the nasty error? I have been banging my head on this all day long and a big part of the last night.

Comment: Just use  `var user = req.body.user;`

Comment: _"The server side code works just fine"_ - Yeah? -> _"500 Internal Server Error"_

Comment: @FaizuddinMohammed that actually worked (or at least, it fixed the previous error). Now I am having this error:
 
    `TypeError: Cannot read property &#39;user&#39; of undefined`
Do you have any idea what this could be?

Comment: `req.body` is somehow undefined. This would not happen otherwise. Are you sure you are doing this inside a POST request?

Comment: Pretty much new to this world, I figured that this should be the POST request, am I wrong? 
`this.http.post(serviceUrl+'/user/signin', JSON.stringify(user), {headers: headers}).subscribe(
        function(response) { console.log("Success Response" + response)},
        (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
            if (err.error instanceof Error) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log(err);
            }
        }
    );`

Comment: Actually, log `req.body` please.